# URL of links on external website appended with internal website's GET

Tags: php, html, url

In a PHP script I am using for my personal/internal website, there is a link (using HTML `<a>` tag) to an external (not mine) website.  The URL of my page is...

`http://localhost/FunctionHome.php?Table=People_Group_Profile_24&Web_Site_Member_ID=43684331&Action=OutputProcess`

...and the link to the external website is something like...

`https://externalwebsite.com/Profile.aspx?id=43684331`

If I click the link to the external website, then a new page opens and takes me to it, and all seems well.  But, on the external website, some (not all) links seem to have the $_GET part of my URL appended to them.  For example, here is a link on the external website, with my URL emboldened...

https://externalwebsite.com/Profile.aspx?tab=Transactions&id=43684331&ret=%2f**FunctionHome%2ephp%3fTable%3dPeople_Group_Profile_24%26Web_Site_Member_ID%3d43684331%26Action%3dOutputProcess**

How did/could the external website append my URL to their links?

How could I prevent my URL from being appended to their links?

Comment: very unclear question, but it sounds to me like if an external website is posting links to your site, then you would need to contact them about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked website could possibly do this by reading the [HTTP Referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer), which would be your site.

You can prevent sending the referer by adding this to the head of your page:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />
```

See [Referer Policy](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-referrer-policy/) for additional, valid meta tags.